# Writing a new column to an existing CSV file

Tags: c#

I am programmatically creating a CSV file, and I am writing 5 columns to it. Later I want to write 1 more column to the CSV file. How do I do that?

Regards
Sanchaita

Comment: Add your new column to all your lines?  Could you show us the code you use to write your file right now?  There are ways to do this easily but it depends on how you structure your code.

Comment: objTextWriter.WriteLine("UserName,Mailbox Path,DateTime,Mails,Contacts,Calender,Error");

Comment: objTextWriter.WriteLine(objCountTableRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() +
                                            "," + objCountTableRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()
                                            + ","+DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: This is how i am adding the values. But now at a different part in the code, I want to open the file and add another coloumn to it

Comment: Uh, don't post your code in the comments section, update your question to include it.  It is hard to read if it's in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest (and from what I know, the only) way of doing this is reading the contents of the CSV file, add the column programmatically, and rewrite the file.

When you try to append new content somewhere in the middle of the file (as opposed to replacing it), the file has to be rewritten to disk anyway, so you shouldn't worry about performance when employing that approach yourself. And as far as I know, this isn't supported by any API calls anyway.

On an unrelated note, I'd suggest you create a temporary file first which has all your modifications, and only replace the original file if all goes well. But that's just good programming practice.

Comment: But than this will lead to Increased Disk IO

Comment: It wouldn't, because even if there was an API function that allowed you to append content in the middle of a file, it'd have to do that in memory and rewrite the new version of the file to disk anyway. A file is written sequentially on disk, and if you add content, the content after it has to be shifted down, causing the same performance overhead.

Comment: The coloumn that ill be adding will be the last one

Comment: The column doesn't matter. The row matters. If you have 3 columns and 2 rows, here's how you can envision the file will be written to disk: A,B,C\nD,E,F, where A,B,C are the contents of the first row, and D,E,F are the contents of the next. Now if you have to add a column to the first row, "\nD,E,F" have to be shifted down physically on the disk. If you have to do that for 10s of rows, it is just as good as (probably worse than) writing a new file to disk.

Comment: +1 for the temporary file ( or even data structure object ) suggestion. You should only write to a final file when you are sure that it is correct.